# What is the correct JSON structure for this while loop?

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I'm a little new to JSON so trying to understand what is the best way to do this. I have two variables: postcode and energyrating that I want to put into JSON and then parse to a for loop.

I can get it to work with one variable but when I have two it doesn't work.

Here is my JSON:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

$postcodeArray = array('postcodes' => array("E6 2JG","SE1 2AQ","DA1 1DZ"), 'energyrating' => array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"));

die(json_encode($postcodeArray));
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
function addNew(postcodes) {
if(postcodes.length > 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {

        var address = postcodes[i];
        var rating = energyrating[i];

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);  

                var image = '../img/markers/' + rating + '.png';
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    icon: image
                });
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
} else {
    alert("Sorry, no data was found.");
}
}
```

How do I get this to work with both variables?

Comment: How is your `addNew()` function called? Also, for the data that you've shown 'postcodes' and 'energyrating' are arrays of different lengths, so how can you loop through both arrays with the same for loop?

Answer (score 0):

What does not work exactly ?

Reading your code, I would say there is an error into your code. The energyrating argument is missing into your addNew function:

```
function addNew(postcodes, energyrating) {
```

Assuming that you call your function like this:

```
addNew(jsonData.postcodes, jsonData.energyrating);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use json variables to store the data like that :

```
$postcodeArray = '{"postcodes":{"0":E6, "1":"2JG", "3":"SE1 2AQ","4":"DA1 1DZ"}, "energyrating":{"0":"A","1":"B","2":"C","3":"D","4":"E","5":"F","6":"G"}}';
```

In the place of

```
$postcodeArray = JSON.parse('postcodes' => array("E6 2JG","SE1 2AQ","DA1 1DZ"), 'energyrating' => array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"));
```

And you can access the values.

Or try `json_decode(postcodes)` in the function `addNew` in first line.